# What is ruling of darood tanjina

Tags: reference-request, bidah, darood

I have heard some people talk about a Darood called Darood Tanjina, to recite in Quran Khawani (in south asia like pakistan ppl gather to read quran). I can't find a reference of that Darood on net, what I found is according to this video it is a [Bidah](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvk0wP1Aq3c&t=124s). if It is a innvoation why people read it thinking it will bring tranquality?

Edit: for reference, what it is, I found it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6d6Jfvq27j4) (not confirmed personally if it or not but word tanjina occur in it)

Comment: hearing this first time, can you post the text in Arabic here so that we can check and give a reply.

Comment: @Shafeek I have edited with link

Answer (score 1):

This Dua'a (darood) has no reference from the Hadith of the prophet nor the companions, but it was mentioned in couple of ancient heritage books, one of them is Kitab al-Qawl al-Badi' fi as-Salati 'ala al-Habib ash-Shafi from [Al-Sakhawi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Sakhawi) (Arabic original [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20231118094006/https://shamela.ws/book/1391/210)) who mentions the original story of the Darood in a story by a shiekh called "Musa the blin":

> He told me that he was riding in a boat in the salt sea. He said, “A wind called the Aqlabiya came upon us. Say, ‘Who will survive it from drowning?’” So I slept and saw the Prophet - may God bless him and grant him peace - and he was saying to me, “Tell the people on the boat to say it a thousand times."

Then he gives the text of the darood. So it's just a story and a Dua, whoever chooses to believe it can use it. However, we have rather many other Dua from the Prophet that were actually verified.

> I found is according to this video it is a Bidah.

Calling things Bidah is very subjective and opinion-based, but for sure there is nothing wrong about the Dua itself that make it a Bidah. The video that you referenced says that its a Bidah because it's filled with Shirk:

> to root for example it says addressing the prophet of allah that you are the one who repels and protects us from famine from illness [..] it says that jibril is your servant

The version that you linked of the darood and the one that I found, however, has nothing to do with that. It roughly says:

> God, bless Muhammad with a blessing with which you save us from all fears and calamities, fulfill all our needs, purify us from all bad deeds, raise us to the highest ranks with you, and bring us to the utmost goals of all good things in life and after death.